# Flip tensorflow values

Tags: tensorflow, bit, logical-operators, flip

I have a tensor which contains only 1s and 0s, like the following:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

What is the fastest method to "flip the bits" and output

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.0-x` should do the trick in your case.